# Custom TableViewCell not displaying label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I'm struggling with a problem I encountered while trying to create a custom UITableViewCell.

I subclassed UITableViewCell in SGTableViewCell and added it in the prototype cell in the storyboard.

[image: Storyboard view of prototype cell]

As you can see the label is connected
[image]

and the cell identifier is set correctly
[image]

Then I linked the label to the SGTableViewCell.h like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
```

and in the .m file I have this code

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

        self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _checkView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
        _checkView.backgroundColor = kGreen;
        _checkView.alpha = 0.0;
        [self addSubview:_checkView];
        self.nameLabel.text = @"Hello";
        }
    return self;
 }
```

But when I use this cell in my tableview using this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Episode *episode = [self.selectedSeason.episodeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    SGTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Episode"];

    UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
    selectionColor.backgroundColor = kSelectionGrey;

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
    cell.backgroundColor = kBackgroundGrey;

    cell.nameLabel.text = episode.name;
    NSLog(@"%@", cell.nameLabel.text);
    cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return cell;
}
```

I get no text at all.

I tried logging the text from each label in each cell and it gives me the right text.
I tried setting programmatically a different disclosure indicator for the custom cell and it did change so everything is allocated and working but label is not displaying.
I honestly have no idea of what's the problem. Did I miss something?
Thank you

PARTIALLY SOLVED:

OK i tried doing the same thing on an empty project and everything worked flawlessly so I checked again my project and found this line

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[SGTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Episode"];
```

Seeing it was not necessary for the empty project i commented this line and everything started working.

The only problem i have now is that if i don't use this line i can't use the custom cell as was intended. In fact my custom cell is swipable using a pan gesture recognizer but without registering my custom class to the tableview seems like the swipe doesn't work.

Sorry for the trouble, seems like i messed up again :/

Comment: You are not calling this line in `cell = [[SGTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: It's called automatically when you dequeue the cell ;)
I put an NSLog in the initWithStyle method and it gets called once for every cell when the tableview appears.

Comment: Try commenting this line `self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];`.

Comment: already did that and it doesn't work. When I NSLog the the text instead of giving me the value it gives null.

Comment: You should try removing all setup in the `initWithStyle` method and the `cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod` (such as `cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;` to only have the label set up. If it works, then some other views/properties are messing with it. This is likely the case that your label is just not visible under something, since logging the `self.nameLabel.text` property gives the desired result.

Comment: >Then I linked the label to the SGTableViewCell.h like this...
Are you sure you make a link in IB, just typing this line "@property IBOutlet..." is not anougth. Also, as others suggested don't allocate it by yourself. Also don'tforget to set @"Episode" as cell Identifier in IB.

Comment: MaratAl  I removed the alloc. The other things were already ok. Still nothing :/ thanks anyway ;)

p4sh4  Removed all subviews, removed the allocation method, label connected and cell identifer set. Still nothing shows up..

Comment: Can you upload your project somewhere and let us have a look at it?

Comment: Yeah, +1 on uploading the project. This is quite mysterious...

Comment: OK i tried doing the same thing on an empty project and everything worked so i checked again my project and found this line

[self.tableView registerClass:[SGTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Episode"];

Seeing it was not necessary for the empty project i commented this line and everything started working.

Comment: Well, hope you learned a lesson not to be a [cargo cult programmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)!

Comment: @p4sh4 Actually i needed that code. Without it my cells are not swipable. now i need to figure out how to make this line of code coexist with the custom labels in the cell...

Comment: If the cell is made in the storyboard you should NOT register the class. Not having that line is not the problem with the swipe not working. When you register class, that means the table view will get the cell's view from the class definition, so if the UI for the cell is made in the storyboard, you won't see any of your subviews. The problem with your swipe is elsewhere.

Comment: @rdelmar i followed this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/21842/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-13 
to make a swipable cell subclassing UITableViewCell and adding to it a  UIPanGestureRecognizer. 
All was working but the problem is i want to have more than two UILabel in my cell. Should I add it programmaticaly? or is there some way to use storyboards and have the swipe integrated?

Comment: You can do it in the storyboard or in code, either should work. If you ad it in code, you should do it in the cell's initWithCoder: method. You can drop the gesture recognizer on the cell to add it in the storyboard, and either connect it to a method in the cell class, or add the method to the controller, and add that method to the recognizer in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't `alloc init` a label that you created in the storyboard, it is already allocated automatically. When you do `self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];`, you reset the `self.nameLabel` property to point to a new empty memory location and not to the label created in the storyboard, hence you can change its `text` property and see the result in NSLog but not in the storyboard because it doesn't refer to that label in the storyboard.

Try removing all initialisation from the `initWithStyle` method (to make sure nothing is covering it such as that subview you create), and everything related to the label in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method (same reason), and try a simple assignment like `self.nameLabel.text = @"Test text"` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, it should work. Then add all your other initialisation.

And yeah, don't forget to input your cell reuse identifier "Episode" in the storyboard.

Comment: I thought that too. I saw other people saying that i should allocate so i did.
Anyway i removed it and removed the subviews and it's still not working, and when i try to access the text after setting it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath all i get is (null).

Comment: Are you sure you connected your IBOutlet from the storyboard to the `SGTableViewCell.h` with ctrl+drag? Does the connection show up in the Connection Inspector when you select the label in the storyboard? Perhaps try removing it and reconnecting again.

Comment: Updated the main question with some screen. 
The connection shows up and is correct and the cell identifier is set.

Comment: Ok. If you don't set the label up in code at all, does the "Custom Label" text you set up in the storyboard show up? Logging the `text` property in this case should also log "Custom Label".

Comment: I can't see it neither in the simulator nor in the nslog. I m still getting null when logging cell.nameLabel.text

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you:

1. Have linked the delegate and the datasource to the view the tablview is housed in.
2. Have that view implement `UITableViewController` and `UITableViewDelegate` (I'm pretty sure it is both of those).
3. Implement the necessary methods, which you seem to have done. You need the `row size, section size, and the add cell` methods
4. After updating the array linked to your tableview, call [`tableView reloadData`]

Have a look at this link:[Tutorial to create a simple tableview app](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I didn't say it but before I was using a regular cell and everything was working fine so the problem is not in the tableview.
The problem is in the label i put in the custom cell

Comment: Why are you using a custom label as oppose to the `label` and `description` areas provided in the original cell?

Comment: Because i need to have more than just two labels in the cell. This is just the first one. Once i get how to make it work i ll add others ;)

Comment: I know this is really late, but I actually just added some custom subviews to my cells, and that seemed to work. I had to do it programatically, have you tried that instead of laying it out by hand? I followed the Apple Documentation.